# Signal R Client Methods are not invoked

Tags: asp.net, signalr, chat

I have developed simple chat system using signal `R`.

In case when internet is disconnect and reconnect after 2 minutes all signal r `server methods` are **invoking** but `client methods` are not getting response.

Can some one tell me what can I do for that?

Comment: I am expecting SignalR backplane will handle that for you.
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr

Answer (score 0):

If the internet disconnects so does the signalR client. You will need to handle reconnecting. The below code is the example from the site below to show you how to handle signalR continuously trying to reconnect in case a disconnect happens.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

More information can be found here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events

Comment: when reconnecting i'm starting hub again then the hub state will change to the connected mode. but i can't get client method response.

Comment: so it does connect back correctly? What do you mean by client method response?

Comment: That mean server method return response. ex - Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);                                             this brodcastMessage is not getting invoked